# Oracle MAF Error "Unable to read DataControl Usages, on loadDataControl for id:"

Tags: oracle, soap, oracle-maf

I have created a simple SOAP web service for a remote DB which is working fine in WebLogic 12c server and also in Jdeveloper HTTP analyzer. When I am using the same web service in the code below, I am getting the following error (I have included the System.out.println outputs in ref. to the flow of the code) I am using Jdeveloper 12C MAF 2.0.0.0.41 on Mac OSx 10.9.

Chk #0
Processing row# 1
Chk #1
Chk #2
**[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - AmxBindingContext - loadDataControlById] Unable to read DataControl Usages, on loadDataControl for id: WLFNewActWS.
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - SynchronizationDC - syncDataFromOfflineToOnline] [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@467c53d3**

```
    public void syncDataFromOfflineToOnline() {
    Trace.log(Utility.FrameworkLogger, Level.INFO, this.getClass(), "syncDataFromOfflineToOnline",
              "Executing syncDataFromOfflineToOnline Method");
    try {
        Connection conn = DBConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String select = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS";
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(select);
        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Chk #0");            
        int rowcount = 0;            
        while (rs.next()) {
            rowcount++;
            System.out.println("Processing row# " + rowcount);

            List namesList = new ArrayList(1);
            List paramsList = new ArrayList(1);
            List typesList = new ArrayList(1);  

            Department dept = new Department();

            dept.setDeptId(rs.getInt("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
            dept.setDeptName(rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_NAME"));
            dept.setMgrId(rs.getInt("MANAGER_ID"));                
            dept.setLocId(rs.getInt("LOCATION_ID"));

            System.out.println("Chk #1");
            GenericType gtDept =
                    GenericTypeBeanSerializationHelper.toGenericType("WLFNewActWS.Types.persistDepartments.arg0", dept);

                System.out.println("Chk #2");                
                namesList.add("arg0");
                paramsList.add(gtDept);
                typesList.add(GenericType.class);   

                AdfmfJavaUtilities.invokeDataControlMethod("WLFNewActWS", null, "persistDepartments", namesList,
                                                           paramsList, typesList);
            System.out.println("Chk #3");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Trace.log(Utility.FrameworkLogger, Level.SEVERE, this.getClass(), "syncDataFromOfflineToOnline",
                  e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Trace.log(Utility.FrameworkLogger, Level.SEVERE, this.getClass(), "syncDataFromOfflineToOnline",
                  e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer to this question, but it may be the answer for someone searching for "**Unable to read DataControl Usages, on loadDataControl for id**"

In my case it is with Oracle MAF, but this also applies to Oracle ADF.

Your web service needs to be in your DataBindings.cpx file.

Something like:

```html
<dataControlUsages>
    <dc id="WLFNewActWS " path="mobile.WLFNewActWS "/>
</dataControlUsages>
```

I cheat and drag something from the WS into a one of pages and have jdeveloper add the record in DataBindings.cpx for me.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs of the binding issue. Please create a reference/binding to 'WLFNewActWS'  in your `amx` page. It will solve your problem...!